# How to zip the database and send it to email in c#?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, xamarin.forms

Hi can anyone help how to zip a database in c# or Xamarin forms and than send it to an email address.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You're missing info. What database is it? You mean zip it and send it programaticlly?

Comment: Its an sql database and yes. i mean to zip it and send it programatically

Comment: You re going to need dedicated smtp/ftp server which is the most important one.

Answer (score 0):

in order to do that then you have to create two stored procedure.

```
         1.) sp_stored_procbackup_db_to_localdrive_as_sqlscript ; 
         2.) create mail profile in your db then create stored procedure for email as follow 

     CREATE PROC dbo.sp_send_email
      declare @results varchar(max)
      declare @subjectText varchar(max)
      declare @databaseName VARCHAR(255)
      SET @subjectText = exec sp_stored_backup_db_to_localdrive_as_sqlscript  
      SET @results = 'your results'
                     -- write the Trigger JOB
      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
           @profile_name = 'SQLAlerts',
           @recipients = 'xxxx@xxxx.com',
           @body = @results,
           @subject = @subjectText,
           @exclude_query_output = 1 --Suppress 'Mail Queued' message
      GO
```

Hope that will help you :D cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have done so far. I get the path on my email.

```
private void sendDbViaEmail(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (File.Exists(Application.Instance.Config.OnePath))
        {
            try
            {

                string zipFilename = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.Instance.Config.OnePath),
                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.Instance.Config.OnePath) + ".zip");


                try
                {
                    if (File.Exists(zipFilename))
                        File.Delete(zipFilename);
                }
                catch { }

                using (var zip = ZipStorer.Create(zipFilename,
                    string.Format("Agente {0}", Application.Instance.Config.CodAge)))
                {
                    zip.AddFile(ZipStorer.Compression.Deflate, Application.Instance.Config.OnePath, Path.GetFileName(Application.Instance.Config.OnePath), "");
                }




                string body = string.Format("OneMobile Lite - agente: {0} {1}", // ??
                                Application.Instance.Config.CodAge,
                                Application.Instance.Config.TbAgente != null ? Application.Instance.Config.TbAgente.Des : "n/a");

                //  System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = null;
                //attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("zipFilename");


                var result = DependencyService.Get<IEmailService>().Send("erinolda.bregu@fshnstudent.info", "OneMobile Lite: Database file", body + " " + zipFilename );

                if (result == null)
                {


                    // TODO cambiare API ServiceCommand.Execute() e non ServiceResult :)
                    App.Navigation.PopModalAsync(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Finished += (object s, EventArgs a) =>
                    {
                        App.Navigation.PopModalAsync(true);
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Application.Instance.Messages.Error(ex);
            }
        }



    }
```